# Where to download h2o 3.10.0.8

Tags: r, h2o

I want to use h2o through R. The latest h2o on is [3.10.0.10](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turing/10/index.html), and the latest integrated h2o version for R is 3.10.0.8, which is not compatible. where can i download previous versions of h2o?

Comment: thanks, but i'm asking for previous version of h2o, not r library for h2o

Comment: have you just tried googling for the version you want? I just did a google search for "h2o 2.9" and got a bunch of results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you play with the URL (change the 10 to an 8) - you'll find:

http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turing/8/index.html

Comment: also, you can download other versions by changing the numbers 4301 to upward or downwards,  http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/4301/index.html